# How would I get the vector3 rotation needed to rotate towards vector3 coordinates

Tags: vector, lua, fivem

So the biggest issue with all the answers I've seen is that I cannot use quaternions. I need to rotate a camera to face a vector3 coordinate position but I can only use x, y, and z for the rotation. I've looked for awhile and can't really figure it out.

I have a raycast hitting a point, I use the point for the target coordinates I need the camera to face, using the cameras position I need to get a vector 3 rotation that I can set the camera to in order for the camera to be pointing directly at the coordinates

Answer (score 0):

> So the biggest issue with all the answers I've seen is that I cannot use quaternions.

This is **plain wrong**. If you can use Lua, you can use quaternions. Simply write your own quaternion implementation in pure Lua (or port an existing one).

> I need to rotate a camera to face a vector3 coordinate position but I
> can only use x, y, and z for the rotation. I've looked for awhile and
> can't really figure it out.

An X, Y & Z rotation vector means you're using Euler angles (which still leaves multiple questions concerning orientation and order of rotation application open).

> I have a raycast hitting a point, I use the point for the target coordinates I need the camera to face, using the cameras position I need to get a vector 3 rotation that I can set the camera to in order for the camera to be pointing directly at the coordinates

First you'll have to determine the **direction** the point is from the camera using the camera pos. You haven't specified which vector library you use, so I'll assume the following:

- `vector.new` creates a new vector from a table;
- `+` and `-` on two vectors perform addition / subtraction;
- the components can be accessed as `.x`, `.y`, `.z`

```lua
local direction = raycast_hit_pos - camera_pos

-- x/z-rotation
local function horizontal_rotation(direction)
    local xz_dist = math.sqrt(direction.x^2 + direction.z^2)
    return math.atan2(direction.y, xz_dist)
end

-- y-rotation
local function vertical_rotation(direction)
    return -math.atan2(direction.x, direction.z)
end

-- gets rotation in radians for a z-facing object
function get_rotation(direction)
    return vector.new{
        x = horizontal_rotation(direction),
        y = vertical_rotation(direction),
        z = 0
    }
end
```

Depending on orientation and the meaning of your rotation axes you might have to shuffle `x`, `y` and `z` around a bit, flipping some signs.

Comment: Thansk for the response, however your solution doesnt work in this use case, and as for quaternions. Its not wether or not they are supported in lua thats the issue but the scripting natives that are provided to me don't allow me to rotate and entity based on quaternions

Comment: @DylanHussain You can convert a quaternion back to an euler rotation though?